# Django filter on generic relationship (unique constraint exception)

Tags: django, django-generic-relations

I have a model below which points to a generic relationship. This can either be a `Post` object or a `Reply` object.

```
class ReportedContent(models.Model):

    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Generic relation for posts and replies
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('reporter', 'object_id', 'content_type')
```

I would like to check if the content_object is already exists before I get a `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` exception.

Django documentation mentioned that:

```
# This will fail
>>> ReportedContent.objects.filter(content_object=content)
# This will also fail
>>> ReportedContent.objects.get(content_object=content)
```

So how can I filter on generic relation? or how can I deal with this exception specifically?

Comment: This seems like it would be a headache. Why not have two foreign key fields, one for a `Post` and one for a `Reply`, and validate that exactly one of the two fields has a value?

Comment: @user2896976 that pretty much easier,thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter by `object_id` and `content_type`.
just make sure you do it right, 
get `content_type` this way:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
# ...

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='name_of_your_app', model='model_name')
```

for handling the exception :

```
if ReportedContent.objects.filter(object_id=content.id,content_type=content_type):
    raise Exception('your exception message')
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old(ish) question, but I thought I'd offer an alternative method in case others run across this post as I did.

Instead of doing a separate `.get()` on the ContentType model, I just incorporate the app/model names in my filter, like this:

```
queryset = ReportedContent.objects.filter(
               object_id=parent_object.id,
               content_type__app_label=app_label,
               content_type__model=model_name
           )
```